# Linux Device Drivers Using a Kernel Module

Tags: linux-kernel

I am trying to get a list of device drivers that have been loaded on linux. I would like to do this inside a kernel module I am working on, I was hoping there was kernel call that I could extend or extern in my module. I am hoping not to have to call lsmod I was hoping there was a way to get a handle on the klist. I was hoping for something like get_all_devices(); or something.

Comment: What do you mean by a "device driver"? are you referring to something like this: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/41817/linux-how-to-find-the-device-driver-used-for-a-device

Comment: Probably correct way to do that would be in userspace. Anyway, the closest thing you have in kernel for this is here: [kernel/module.c](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L103http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/kernel/module.c#L103). `modules` list contains all loaded modules. It can be accessed from userspace via `/proc/modules`.

Comment: Why do you want to do that in the first place? I'm asking because it can be XY problem.

Comment: I am looking to be able to get information on the devices that are installed on a linux machine. It has to be done in kernel space and I am looking for something that would be as secure as possible. I am trying to make it difficult for someone to alter my configuration.

Comment: That can be done by not using modules. Or by using module signing, and throwing away all modules you don't want.

Comment: There was a hack-patch that prevents to load more modules. Very simple, very strong.